# Package is not in GOROOT for local package in module for golang 1.19

Tags: go

Here is my directory structure

```
    myapp/
        go.mod
        mymodule/
            main.go
            mypackage/
                mypackage.go
```

`mypackage.go`

```
package mypackage

import "fmt"

func MyFunc() {
    fmt.Println("hellow")
}
```

`main.go`

```
package main

import "myapp/mypackage"


func main() {
    mypackage.MyFunc()
}
```

Currently I am in `myapp/mymodule` when I `go build` I run into

`package myapp/mymodule is not in GOROOT`

I am using golang 1.19

What is the proper setup for importing sub package in local to the parent module?

Comment: The import name should be how your package is initialized in go.mod. What does your go.mod look like?

Comment: Use proper module names like myapp.mycompany. Set up your module according to go.dev/doc. Use proper import path of the form modulename/relative/path (myapp.mycompany/mymodule/mypackage. There are no "subpackages", all packages are equal The name of the language is Go. Read and follow go.dev./doc!

Comment: Import the package using path "modulename/mymodule/mypackage" where *modulename* is the module name in go.mod.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["package XXX is not in GOROOT" when building a Go project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845013/package-xxx-is-not-in-goroot-when-building-a-go-project)