# Solve: package foo is not in GOROOT

Tags: go, makefile

I am trying to make my Go project compile, but the way to fix compilation errors is not obvious.  Simplified example follows.

```
// filename: ~/myprojects/automate_things/automate_things.go
package main
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/melbahja/goph"
    "github.com/gleich/logoru"
)

func main() {
  // insert many things here
}
```

Now I use `make dep` (with `Makefile`, below) to build a `go.mod` and try to get all the dependencies, but this does not get them because I keep seeing `package foo is not in GOROOT` errors.

```
# filename: ~/myprojects/automate_things/Makefile
GOOS=linux

GO_SOURCE_FILE=automate_things.go
GO_BINARY_FILE=automate_things
GO_BIN_DIR=bin/

.SILENT: build
.DEFAULT_GOAL := build

build:
        -make fmt
        make dep
        go build $(GO_SOURCE_FILE)
        if [ "$(PLATFORM)" = "Linux" ]; then \
                GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags "-s -w" -o ./$(GO_BINARY_FILE) $(GO_SOURCE_FILE); \
        elif [ "$(PLATFORM)" = "Darwin" ]; then \
                GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=darwin go build -ldflags "-s -w" -o ./$(GO_BINARY_FILE) $(GO_SOURCE_FILE); \
        fi
.PHONY: build

fmt:
        go fmt $(GO_SOURCE_FILE)
.PHONY: fmt

dep:
        -rm go.mod
        -rm go.sum
        go mod init automate_things
        go mod tidy
        go mod download
.PHONY: dep
```

This is my `~/.bashrc`, which exports several relevant go env variables.

```
# filename: ~/.bashrc
# Build the default GOROOT (re-run the command as root)

mkdir -p /usr/local/go
export GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org
mkdir -p ~/gobin/bin
export GOPATH=~/gobin
#export GO111MODULE=auto

export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

This is the `go.mod`, which is generated by my `Makefile` (`make dep`)

```
// go.mod
module automate_things

go 1.20

require (
        github.com/gleich/logoru v0.0.0-20230101033757-d86cd895c7a1
        github.com/melbahja/goph v1.4.0
)

require (
        github.com/fatih/color v1.10.0 // indirect
        github.com/kr/fs v0.1.0 // indirect
        github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.8 // indirect
        github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.12 // indirect
        github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1 // indirect
        github.com/pkg/sftp v1.13.5 // indirect
        golang.org/x/crypto v0.6.0 // indirect
        golang.org/x/sys v0.5.0 // indirect
)
```

This is what I see when I `make dep`

```
$ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/me/myprojects/automate_things'
go fmt automate_things.go
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/myprojects/automate_things'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/me/myprojects/automate_things'
rm go.mod
rm go.sum
go mod init automate_things
go: creating new go.mod: module automate_things
go: to add module requirements and sums:
        go mod tidy
go mod tidy
go: finding module for package github.com/melbahja/goph
go: finding module for package github.com/gleich/logoru
go: found github.com/gleich/logoru in github.com/gleich/logoru v0.0.0-20230101033757-d86cd895c7a1
go: found github.com/melbahja/goph in github.com/melbahja/goph v1.4.0
go mod download
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/myprojects/automate_things'
../../gobin/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.6.0/ssh/transport.go:8:2: package bufio is not in GOROOT (/home/me/src/bufio)
../../gobin/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-colorable@v0.1.8/noncolorable.go:4:2: package bytes is not in GOROOT (/home/me/src/bytes)
```

So let's try to download directly with `go get` and sudo to squash any potential permissions problems...

```
$ sudo /home/me/bin/go get github.com/melbahja/goph
go: downloading github.com/melbahja/goph v1.4.0
go: downloading github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1
go: downloading github.com/pkg/sftp v1.13.5
go: downloading golang.org/x/crypto v0.6.0
go: downloading github.com/kr/fs v0.1.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.5.0
github.com/melbahja/goph imports
        context: package context is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/context)
github.com/melbahja/goph imports
        errors: package errors is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/errors)
github.com/melbahja/goph imports
```

#### Question

My `go` binary is in `~/bin/go`.

What is the most efficient way to get / specify dependencies in my `Makefile` (without listing endless sub-deps) and make this project compile?  I want to fix all the compilation problems listed above.

[RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) is not an answer.  RTFM with a direct link to the documentation **that works** is an answer.

Comment: Do not create go.mod. It is probably not what you thing. You do go mod init _once_ and then add dependences and _check in_ go.mod and go.sum. Doing make dep is nonsensical. Then _never_ _ever_ (literally **NEVER**) set GOROOT. It's not what you think it is. You do not need to set it if you cannot explain exactly what it does. Let me repeat: Do not set GOROOT! While here: It's end 2023: Stop using GO111MODULE. Just forget about it. I urge you to consult the documentation on go.dev on how to write and build Go code as your way is _unsuitable_.

Comment: Yes, what I'm doing is broken; that much is obvious and therefore I ask.  Perhaps you'd like to scub all the things you said not to do from google AND stackoverflow because the broken is littered all over the internet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["package XXX is not in GOROOT" when building a Go project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845013/package-xxx-is-not-in-goroot-when-building-a-go-project)

Comment: You seem to have done multiple incorrect things that are making it hard to figure out what went wrong when. I would clean out everything and start fresh. Install the latest version of go. Don’t set any environment variables aside from normal PATH additions. The “How to Write Go Code” doc is the most concise document on building a go package and module, and you can compare what you’ve done against that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $ sudo /home/me/bin/go get github.com/melbahja/goph

- The title of the question (and originally, the question body) mentioned `GOROOT`

  - You [should NOT set GOROOT to anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45529403/667301).
  - I have no idea why Go still mentions `GOROOT` in an error message at all.
- Short story, your Go install seems to be broken... to fix it:

---

1. Download a proper Go source tree for your processor arch (usually it's going to be amd64 for a typical linux install) from [go.dev/dl](https://go.dev/dl/)
2. `cd /usr/local`
3. Extract the tarball as root
4. `cd ~/bin`
5. `ln -s /usr/local/go/bin/go go`
6. `ln -s /usr/local/go/bin/gofmt gofmt`
7. `cd` into your project directory and build the way you have your `Makefile` set up.  It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

- Use a proper installation of Go.
- Do not set GOROOT
- Do not set GO111MODULE
- Do go mod init once
- Do go mod tidy after adding dependencies (e.g. with go get) and check in go.mod and go.sum afterwards
- Build with go build

Comment: `$ go build <insert-carriage-return-here>
../../gobin/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.6.0/ssh/transport.go:8:2: package bufio is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/bufio)`.  As I said above, I am not interested in adding sub-deps.  I removed `GOROOT` and `GO111MODULE` from `~/.bashrc` as you requested in your comment... my question was updated